# Nearby blocks Voice Recognition Intents while listening to messages

Tags: android, google-nearby

We are experimenting the following issue with nearby.
When the application launches we subscribe for Nearby Messages, which is working fine. But when I try to launch the Speech Recognition Intent it opens but it cannot use the microphone (which it makes sense since it's being used by the Nearby API).

A fix for this was to disconnect/unsubscribe but some times it takes more time to do so (from 5 to 10 seconds) so the Speech Intent keeps failing until Nearby release the microphone.

Is there any way to just release the microphone without doing the disconnect/unsubscribe?